# Create Django sessions

Tags: python, django, session

I'm currently facing with a problem, in my web app if 2 users log in and then each one wants to make an operation(e.g. add a review) these 2 reviews will appear in the database as being from the same person(last logged in user). I have documented and know that sessions have to be made, but I can't figure it out how. From the examples found I understand that something like that is needed

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

if user is not None:
    login(request, user)
    request.session['username'] = username
    return redirect('index')
else:
    return render(request, 'library/login.html')
```

and then in profile if I want to print the username always, to all users, will show the **last** logged in user

```
class Profil(View):
    template_name = 'library/profile.html'

    def get(self, request):
        print(request.session['username'])
        # the rest of the code
```

Can anyone please explain to me where I am wrong and how can i correct it? An example would be perfect.

P.S.: Apologize in advance if you think it's a stupid question.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with sessions. Why do you think it does? Rather, you should be showing us the code where you save the reviews and associate them with the user.

Comment: The above code is for testing only. Let's say that are logged in 3 users in the same time(A, B and C), when each user accesses profile.html I want just to print his username. I expect to see the name of each user(A, B, C), but print C, C, C because C is the **last user logged in**. Somehow overwriting other accounts because if I refresh A's page the C's account will appear.

Comment: No, that will not happen as that is not what sessions do. But as I said sessions are not what you need to use here, and you should show the relevant code.

Comment: I just have to understand on this small example what I have to do to show each user's username(A, B and C) when accessing profile.html and refreshing the page

Comment: ok, let's say that I want information about de user, if I refresh the A's page will appear C's information. `c.execute("SELECT first_name, last_name, age from users where username=%s", [username])` for example

Comment: This code *will* show the current user's information. There is **no way** it would do anything else. But you don't need sessions here anyway, because you could do `request.user.username`, and it has no relevance to your original question, which is about storing the information about who created a review and which we can't help you with until you show the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly defines session you can easily get username by " request.user.username " and in  your review model you can add an foreign key of user table indicating which user is adding the review.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately using request.user.username has the same strange behavior: A log in and on page shows his information(name) and then B log in and on page shows his information too; now is the strange thing, if A refreshes his page B's information will appear on page(request.user.username should not be the problem, it gives me the username, but it gives B's username)